# Problem with testing service that utilises data from mongodb repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to test a service that has a mongodb repository. I dont know how to write tests that utilise it though and when I try to create entries from the testing class I keep on getting null pointer exception when I call a method from the mongodb repository. My repository class is called

```
        TagPreferencesRepository
```

and the exception is thrown when I call

```
tagPreferencesRepository.deleteAllByTag(tag);
```

I have declared `TagPreferencesRepository` using `@Mock`:

```
@Mock TagPreferencesRepository tagPreferencesRepository;
```

and the method throwing the exception is called from inside a method in the testing class, that is annotated with `@Before`

Methods in the testing class annotated with `@Before`:

```
 @Before
 public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }
```

and:

```
@Before
public TagPreferences setUp() {
    tagPreferencesRepository.deleteAllByTag(tagEnum);

    ...
}
```

Comment: add the method annotated with @Before to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mock is not being correctly initialized. 
It could be that you are not injecting the mock to the instance of what you want to test. Do you have a @InjectMock annotation?
Also, make sure that you are using jUnit for your annotations. I once had a similar experience because I was using org.junit.jupiter.api for some of the annotations instead of org.junit.
Example skeleton:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class TestSomeService()
{
    @InjectMock
    SomeService someService;

    @Mock 
    TagPreferencesRepository tagPreferencesRepository;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void SomeTest(){
        TagEnum tag = SomeTag;
        // if deleteAllByTag is void
        doNothing().when(tagPreferencesRepository).deleteAllByTag(tag);
        someResult = someService.someMethod(tag);
        // assert something
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have @InjectMocks annotation refering to the service class.